# Is it necessary to set hEvent on the OVERLAPPED structure when doing I/O completion ports?

Tags: windows, serial-port, iocp, io-completion-ports

I'm using I/O completion ports on Windows for serial port communication (we will potentially have lots and lots of serial port usage). I've done the usual, creating the IOCP, spinning up the I/O threads, and associating my `CreateFile()` handle with the IOCP (`CreateFile()` was called with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`). That's all working fine. I've set the `COMMTIMEOUTS` all to 0 except `ReadIntervalTimeout` which is set to `MAXDWORD` in order to be completely async.

In my I/O thread, I've noticed that `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` blocks indefinitely. I'm using an `INFINITE` timeout. So I put a `ReadFile()` call right after I associate my handle with the IOCP. Now that causes `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` to release immediately for some reason with 0 bytes transferred, but there's no errors (it returns true, GetLastError() reports 0). I obviously want it to block if there's nothing for it to do. If I put another `ReadFile()` after GetQueuedCompletionStatus(), then another thread in the pool will pick it up with 0 bytes transferred and no errors.

In the examples I've seen and followed, I don't see anyone setting the `hEvent` on the `OVERLAPPED` structure when using IOCP. Is that necessary? I don't care to ever block IOCP threads -- so I'll never be interested in `CreateEvent(...) | 1`.

If it's not necessary, what could be causing the problem? `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` needs to block until data arrives on the serial port.

Are there any good IOCP serial port examples out there? I haven't found a complete serial port + IOCP example out there. Most of them are for sockets. In theory, it should work for serial ports, files, sockets, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out -- I wasn't calling `SetCommMask()` with `EV_RXCHAR | EV_TXEMPTY` and then `WaitCommEvent()` with the `OVERLAPPED` struct. After I did that, my IOCP threads behaved as expected. `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` returned when a new character appeared on the port. I could then call `ReadFile()`.

So to answer the original question: "no, you don't need to set hEvent for IOCP with serial ports."

Comment: I realize this is a very old post. I'm wondering if you can post an example though. I've got IOCP working for sockets, and I'm using the same IOCP-specific classes for serial ports. I can't quite get it to work. The transmits are OK but I can't seem to get the receive events working. I've tried combinations (and different order) for ReadFile(), SetCommMask(), and WaitCommEvent() but I haven't been able to get it right.